# On a limiting value of a matrix exponential

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, matrix-calculus, matrix-exponential

$\mathbf {The \ Problem \ is}:$ If $A$ and $B$ are two bdd linear operators on a Banach space, then show that

$\lim_{n \to \infty} (e^\frac{A}{\sqrt n}e^\frac{B}{\sqrt n}e^\frac{-A}{\sqrt n}e^\frac{-B}{\sqrt n})^n = e^{(AB-BA)}$

$\mathbf {My \ approach}:$ Actually, we know $e^\frac{T}{\sqrt n} = I + \frac{T}{\sqrt n} + o(\frac{1}{\sqrt n}) $ where $T$ is a bdd linear operator and $o$ is Landau's little order notation , but the multiplication is getting bigger and confusing .

Is there any other better way to prove this thing except this multiplication .

A small hint is warmly appreciated .

Comment: Actually, multiplying out up to $1\over n$ looks like a reasonable strategy.

Comment: Remember that if $x_n\to x$ then $(1+ x_n/n)^n\to e^{x}$ in any Banach algebra.

Comment: Perhaps it could be proven as a consequence of the [Lie product formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2030671/81360)

Comment: An attempt: Denote $E_n = \exp[A/\sqrt{n}]$. We note that
$$
E_n \exp[B/\sqrt{n}]E_n^{-1} = \exp[[E_nBE_n^{-1}]/\sqrt{n}].
$$
Note that we have 
$$
E_nBE_n^{-1} = B + [AB - BA]/\sqrt{n} + o(1/\sqrt{n}).
$$
Now, write
$$
\exp(A/\sqrt{n})\exp(B/\sqrt{n})\exp(-A/\sqrt{n})\exp(-B/\sqrt{n}) = \\
\exp(B/\sqrt{n} + [AB - BA]/n + o(1/n))\exp(-B/\sqrt{n}).
$$
Via the Lie product formula, we have
$$
[\exp(B/\sqrt{n} + [AB - BA]/n + o(1/n))\exp(-B/\sqrt{n})]^{\sqrt{n}} = \\
\exp(B - B + [AB - BA]/\sqrt{n}) + o(1) = \\
\exp([AB - BA]/\sqrt{n}) + o(1)
$$

Comment: @Ben Grossman, yes , I wad trying to apply that formula, but I couldn't do it up to last .

Comment: The problem with this attempt is that the error term for 
$$
\exp(E_nBE_n^{-1})^{\sqrt{n}} - \exp([AB - BA]/\sqrt{n}) 
$$
is too large to guarantee the desired result.

Comment: If we take $e^\frac{±T}{\sqrt n} = I ± \frac{T}{\sqrt n} + \frac{T^2}{2n} + o(\frac{1}{\sqrt n})$ , and then multiply all the expressions, we may get the result .